# AngularJS, ui-grid, how to set color for specified rows

Tags: angularjs

I have problems to set color for Angular ui-grid specified rows.
I know I can use row template as the following.
But "row.sequence" doesn't take effect.
Can somebody paste code here to show me how to set color for specified row based on row index?

```
var rowtpl='<div ng-class="{\'blue\':row.sequence==1}"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';
  // Danfer change: end
  this.gridOptions={
        appScopeProvider: this,
        headerTemplate:'./src/main/layout/modules/user/partials/headerTemplate.html',
        rowTemplate:rowtpl,
        enableSorting:true,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar :1,
        minRowsToShow: 10,
        multiSelect : true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableVerticalScrollbar :1,
        enableColumnMenus:false,
        enableFiltering: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [50, 60, 70, 80],
        paginationPageSize: 50,
        onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) { 
              lcl.gridApi = gridApi;

        }
  };
```

---

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use "grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)", this is working.

var rowtpl='';

Answer (score 0):

```
There is another problem. By setting row template, I can't update row color dynamically.

Here, 5 is static number pre-defined. It is working. The following row template can change row 5 to to blue color.
************************
var rowtpl='<div ng-class="{\'blue\':grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)==5}"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';

************************

But I want to to like this:
When I loop the grid data, if meet some condition, I mark the row index. Then use this row index to set the row color. If I pass the "rowIndex" to "rowtpl", it is not working.
*************************
...
var rowtpl='<div ng-class="{\'blue\':grid.renderContainers.body.visibleRowCache.indexOf(row)==this.rowIndex}"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';

this.gridOptions={ appScopeProvider: this, headerTemplate:'./src/main/layout/modules/user/partials/headerTemplate.html', rowTemplate:rowtpl, enableSorting:true, enableHorizontalScrollbar :1, minRowsToShow: 10, multiSelect : true, enableRowSelection: true, enableSelectAll: true, enableVerticalScrollbar :1, enableColumnMenus:false, enableFiltering: true, paginationPageSizes: [50, 60, 70, 80], paginationPageSize: 50, onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) { lcl.gridApi = gridApi; 
...
this.notifyService.getMsg('GridDataLoaded', function(_event,_data){
    lcl.myData = _data;
    lcl.gridOptions.data = lcl.myData;
    for(let i=0; i< lcl.gridOptions.data.length; i++){
    if(lcl.userGridService.oldDefaulPortfolio.portfolioId === lcl.gridOptions.data[i].portfolioId){
        lcl.rowIndex = i;
        break;
     }
    }
    lcl.init();
});

*********************
```